# Solaris 11 find empty folders (-empty not work)

Tags: solaris, directory, terminal, find

How to find empty dir and delete in Solaris 11.

I try this:

`find . -type d -empty`

Output:

`find: bad option -empty
find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list`

Answer (score 1):

There is no -empty in Solaris by default, if you have `/usr/xpg4/bin/find` it should support it

Another way is to script it like:

`find . -type d|while read name; do if (( $(ls -al $name|wc -l) == 3 )); then echo $name; fi; done`

- Based on the work of user lasse, full discussion here - https://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/49739-how-find-empty-folders-without-using-empty.html

Answer (score 1):

The `-empty` argument is a non-standard extension to the [POSIX-standardized `find` utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html).

Solaris 11 should have GNU `find` installed as `gfind` somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another example. This should work faster.

It is based on output of 'ls -ed' command, which replaces size field (fifth) for directories with information of its contents. Empty directories will always have "2" in this field.

Also xargs is used to reduce number of commands to exec.

```
find . -type d | xargs -i ls -ed {} | awk '{if ($5=="2"){ print $0 }}'
```